# How Python psycopg2 query in condition with uuid array

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

For given a table

```
create table test_db (
  id uuid
)
```

In Python with library psycopg2, we can do query

```
cursor.execute("select * from test_db where id in" +
   " ('5ed11bbf-ffd1-4124-ba3d-5e392dc9db96','14acfb5b-3b09-4728-b3b3-8cd484b310db')")
```

But if I parameterize `id`, change to

```
cursor.execute("select * from testdb where id in (%s)",
   ("'5ed11bbf-ffd1-4124-ba3d-5e392dc9db96','14acfb5b-3b09-4728-b3b3-8cd484b310db'",))
```

It's not working, says

> psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "'5ed11bbf-ffd1-4124-ba3d-5e392dc9db96','14acfb5b-3b09-4728-b3b3-8cd484b310db'"

How can I use `in (%s)` with uuid array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank @piro's answer, after try several time, got the working code

```
cursor.execute("select * from testdb where id = any(%s::uuid)",
   (['5ed11bbf-ffd1-4124-ba3d-5e392dc9db96',
     '14acfb5b-3b09-4728-b3b3-8cd484b310db'],))
```

and `id = any(%s::uuid)` can't be replaced with `id in (%s::uuid)`.

Answer (score 1):

One %s per value.

```
cursor.execute(
   "select * from testdb where id in (%s, %s)",
   ('5ed11bbf-ffd1-4124-ba3d-5e392dc9db96','14acfb5b-3b09-4728-b3b3-8cd484b310db')
)
```

Comment: The input ids is a list. Or do this way `cursor.execute(f'select * from testdb where id in ({','.join(['%s'] * len(ids)}),  ids)`

Answer (score 1):

You have extra quotes, so you are passing only one argument which is a string.

You might use a tuple and use `IN`, but using a list and `any()` is a better option because it won't explode in your face as soon as you pass an empty list.

```py
cursor.execute("select * from testdb where id = any(%s)",
   ([UUID('5ed11bbf-ffd1-4124-ba3d-5e392dc9db96'), UUID('14acfb5b-3b09-4728-b3b3-8cd484b310db')],))
```

It might work without using UUID but you are just confusing the type system that way.

Comment: cursor.execute("select * from testdb where id = any(%s)",
                       (['5ed11bbf-ffd1-4124-ba3d-5e392dc9db96', '14acfb5b-3b09-4728-b3b3-8cd484b310db'],))

E       psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: operator does not exist: uuid = text
E       LINE 1: select * from testdb where id = any(ARRAY['5ed11bbf...
E                                              ^
E       HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: As it says on the tin, you can add an explicit cast, such as using `%s::uuid[]` as placeholder.